# Using -std=c++0x with gfortran

Tags: c++, c++11, gfortran

I have large program which uses C, C++, and Fortran.  I've always found it easiest to get this to link properly using the "gfortran" front end, even though my main is C. gfortran knows about a lot of Fortran special stuff that needs to be linked in.

Now, however, I need to include `unordered_map`, which with my compiler (gcc 4.4.1 on Mac OS X 10.7.5) seems to require the `-std=c++0x` option.  I discovered and verified that by compiling a small test program with C++ only.

But if I use the `-std=c++0x` option with gfortran, that produces a huge number of link errors starting with:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::data() const", referenced from:
```

Meanwhile, if I go back to my large program, and replace the gfortran with g++ or gcc, I also get a huge number of link errors, starting with:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "__gfortran_compare_string", referenced from:
```

Comment: Try linking with `g++` and pass the `-lgfortran`. That should resolve the undefined Fortran stuff.

Comment: Does passing `-lstdc++` help? Your errors seems to stem from gfortran (rightly) not linking to the standard C++ library (or, when using g++, not linking to the Fortran library - which as Ali points out can be done by passing `-lgfortran` to g++).

Comment: Linking using g++ and -lgfortran has fixed the problem.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

I now link using g++ with the -lgfortran switch, and that lets me use -std=c++0x and doesn't leave me with undefined c++ or fortran symbols.

Comment: BTW, it's time (since 2 years ago) to use `-std=c++11` instead of `-std=c++0x`